# Access optional keys in object, where key is a literal in a literal union type without error "Object is possibly 'undefined'"

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have a type Fields

```js
export type NodeId =
    | "a-index"
    | "b-index"
    | "c-index"

export type Fields = {
    [id in NodeId]?: {
        [sectionId: string]: {
            [name: string]: string;
        };
    }
};
```

Why does the first set error with `Object is possibly 'undefined'`, but not the second set?

```js
const test: Fields = {};

const id = "a-index";

// Why does this error
let resultA;
if (test[id]) {
  resultA = test[id]["somesection"]
            ^^^^^^^^
            error TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.
}

// But this works fine?
let resultB;
if (test["a-index"]) {
  resultB = test["a-index"]["somesection"]
}
```

The only difference being that I assigned `id` to a variable. Even explicitly typing `id` as `NodeId` doesn't satisfy typescript.

See [typescript playground here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcByEAmwCSm4C8AsAFBzlwA%20cARAIYC0AlgHbYg2kVW0BGzbUJzIVqNAMYD2w0qVCRYCZKgBiTYABtMAZ0JwA3lwoBtJvlbosuTAF0A-AC4DR7uWPbg4mEwgs8T7RgoVgBzGydDEVdXYxY6AFtgAKDQ8LhA4JYQgG4XVwBfXKi4fNJC2RJxX0CEYECnNU0dPX1yklIqlhqzPXopISLSAHohuABiCbG4AHUAC0Q4TAg6hFmmXWAoKGhSDWB4KDqAVw0YAEEipgAzOAAKGDqYU1sASmcRQ%200T870HwOebMYaNoIIkPF4fCwaDYyhURuNJnAAEJHeAsCDwGBrbR2Xb7OCfb5Iy43e6PIGMVjSGxvSLkQmnJG-cl9KlCQHA0F1TzeXzQ2EkIA)

Comment: I think this is just how TypeScript works in this instance (you could call it a bug). A simple fix is to reassign first like `testSections = test[id] ... if (testSections)`.

Comment: This is due to [microsoft/TypeScript#10530](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10530); checking for duplicate questions now

Comment: didn't find anything obvious... wrote up an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue, [microsoft/TypeScript#10530](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10530).  The problem is that the compiler only spends time narrowing the type of an object property if the property access is *direct*, either by using a dotted identifier or by using bracket index with a string literal.  So your `resultB` version works:

```
let resultB;
if (test["a-index"]) {
    resultB = test["a-index"]["somesection"]
}
```

But the `resultA` version doesn't because `id`, even though it is a `const` whose type is the literal `"a-index"`, is a variable and the compiler doesn't do narrowing for it.  According to [microsoft/TypeScript#10565](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/10565), an initial attempt to address this, adding this functionality significantly worsens the compiler perfomance.  I guess having to check every possible indexing-into-an-object is more expensive than the potential control flow narrowing saves you.

The workaround here, in the case where you can't just replace `id` with a string literal, is to do the property access *once* and save its result to a new variable.  Then type guards should work on this variable as expected:

```
let resultA;
const testId = test[id];
if (testId) {
    resultA = testId["somesection"]
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcByEAmwCSm4C8AUHKXAD5wBEAhgLQCWAdtiFSWZVQEaMujsyFagGM+rdkSKhIsBMlQAxBsAA2mAM6E4Abw6kA2g3zN0WXJgC6AfgBcuuPqFwDG4CJgMITPPY0woZgBzS3s9ZwiXJhoAW2A-AODQuH9ApiCAbichAF8s3KI8qRFvfwRgf3tlNU1tHSKiEqYy421acQEsolVgeCgKgFdVGABBLKaymAqYPG0p-yMrLIYAMzgACnmZzABKXSd+jSHRuem8AyoNCDi3Dy8mKktCqR6+weGAIWW1zemL+mYEkse3CZEOxw+pwW7UBAksFyuN3cnm8j0KQA)